# Analogue to fetchmail that can delete mail older than X

Tags: email

Fetchmail only has the option to delete mail from the server or not. Is there something that exists that does basically exactly what fetchmail does, except which also supports the option to only delete mail older than some time period?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is getmail.

http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/

You want the `delete_after (integer)` attribute:

> if set, getmail will delete messages
>   this number of days after first seeing
>   them, if they have been retrieved and
>   delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you aren't running in daemon mode. You can configure a separate fetchmail instance to run periodically with the flush flag.

Such as:

`#Flush fetchmail weekly
1    1 * * 1 cd /home/username; /usr/bin/fetchmail --flush`